# How to disable autocomplete in address fields for Safari?

Tags: html, macos, autocomplete, safari

I have a form where I've implemented an autosuggest dropdown (via jQueryUI) so that a user can search for a contact in our app and have their information auto-filled. I want autocomplete to be disabled on the form, but Safari (on macOS) is ignoring `autocomplete="off"`. I have specified autocomplete to be off on the input fields, as well as in the `<form>` tag. This form is for a physical mailing address for a friend, and Safari is showing matching contacts from Contacts.app... but it is overlaying a dropdown on top of my autosuggest dropdown. How do I force Safari to stop showing this dropdown?

[image]

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/listings/sailing/create_customized_card" autocomplete="off" class="new_greeting_card" id="new_greeting_card" method="post">
...
  <li>
    <input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" class="validate required" id="to_name" name="delivery[to_name]" placeholder="First &amp; last name" size="30" type="text" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" class="validate required" id="to_address_street_1" name="to_address[street_1]" placeholder="Street 1" size="30" type="text" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" id="to_address_street_2" name="to_address[street_2]" size="30" type="text" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input autocomplete="off" class="validate required city" id="to_address_city" name="to_address[city]" placeholder="City" size="30" type="text" />
    <select class="validate required state" id="to_address_state" name="to_address[state]">
    <option value="AK">AK</option>
    ...
    </select>
    <input autocomplete="off" class="validate required zip" id="to_address_zip_code" name="to_address[zip_code]" pattern="(\d{5}([\-]\d{4})?)" placeholder="Zip" size="30" type="text" />
  </li>
...
</form>
```

FYI - I know that most browsers ignore `autocomplete="off"` for username and password fields, but these are address fields for a contact.

Comment: For Chrome, you can set autocorrect to something semantically correct, but invalid according to the specifications. i.e. `autocorrect="new-contact-name"`. This still does not work in Safari though. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems you can't disable autocomplete in a similar way.
Safari looks for certain keywords in the `id` of the element and if there is something like "name", "address", "e-mail" etc., it enables the autocomplete function (tested on Safari 10.1.1).
So, the only simple workaround that I've found is to use a different `id` that doesn't trigger the autocomplete function.

EDIT: I found out that Safari also uses the `placeholder` attribute to determine whether to enable autocomplete function or not.

Comment: Hi Matteo, are you sure about this? I tryed changing the id but it still ask me to fill it with data from my contacts...

Comment: Yes, I've tested this behavior on different fields.Have you changed the id only in the inspector? Because it doesn't work this way, you have to reload the page to see the effect.
Or maybe have you changed it to another "relevant" id that also triggers the autocomplete?

Comment: I tried changing it multiple times, even using strings with no-meaning. it looks like safari remembers my previous fillings even if I changed field name and id

Comment: That sounds very strange to me. How can Safari identify an input field without an id (or name)? Have you tried restarting Safari?

Comment: THANK YOU, Matteo! The tip about the `placeholder` attribute is on point, and I haven't seen it mentioned anywhere before. I had the word "Name" in an input placeholder that was bringing up a list of contact names that I didn't want, and I've been trying to figure out why for days. Tweaking the `placeholder` text did the trick. Thank you again!

Comment: I second the placeholder story, changed `... email ...` to `... notification ...` and it stopped. Safari still does this then

Comment: What are you changing the placeholder to? @MatteoMilesi  in a case where we need to say a specific.  ie Client First Name  for a first name field.

Comment: @CanuckT in the design system I was using there was a label near the input to define the field role, so we decided to use the label to say that the field was the "Client name" and to change the placeholder into "Start typing..." (it was an autocomplete field).

Comment: I had the exact same issue with a placeholder containing the word "name". But I wanted to keep that way (I was a search field and my placeholder was "Find by name..."). Turns out, including the word "search" in the id and name attributes solved it, even with "name" in the placeholder ! Safari must disable its autofill if he thinks it is a search field.

Answer (score 15):

Just to add one wrinkle to the other fine answers...

I found empirically that Safari get its hints from a) the name of the field, b) the associated label, or c) adjacent text. It figures out things like field names "name", "firstname", "lastname", and labels or adjacent text like "name", "First name", "Last name".

In my application, it was competing with a custom autofill. I defeated my dropdown as follows:

I changed my field name from `xx_firstname` to `mxyzptlk`, and the label from `First Name` to `F&zwnj;irst N&zwnj;ame`. The `&zwnj;` character is a zero width non-joiner. You can't see it on the screen, but it appears to defeat Safari - at least for now!

Edit made by [@BIUBIU UP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19507126/biubiu-up): If you are using React or Vue, you may need Unicode values for &zwnj: '\u200c'.

Comment: This answer is what saved the day. Thank you for this brilliant hack.

Comment: Huh. There are still creative minds on this site. Nice work, btw!

Comment: Incredible. This is the only thing that solved a Safari Autofill bug for me. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, overlapping dropdowns. What you could do is change the 'name' string (in the input's placeholder) by changing one or some of the characters into a homoglyph.

What I did was change the 'a' character with 'ɑ' character. Looks a bit weird, but it's worth getting rid of the annoying overlap.

Just make sure you document it in the html-code.

Also, I noticed that the field's description in a P tag above the input was used by Safari to trigger the autocomplete function.

Comment: Unless the character is also a homophone, again, that'll trip up screen reader users.

Answer (score -2):

Another hack I found based on @worddragon answer was to use   and letter-spacing.

```
  disableAutoFillHack(localizedContent) {
    return localizedContent.split('').join('&nbsp;');
  }
```

...and then add // adjust the letter spacing based on the font sizes

```
  .autofill__disable {
    letter-spacing: -0.125em;
  }
```

Comment: If you try reading out that content with Voiceover, you'll notice that it spells it out (for example, "F-i-r-s-t n-a-m-e"), instead of reading the words. This doesn't currently happen (macOS 10.14.6, Safari 13.0.5) if you use `&zwnj;` between the letters of the words instead.