# Remove safari contacts dropdown from inputs

Tags: safari

When typing in input fields safari is creating a dropdown based contacts. I can't figure out how to hide this dropdown. I am able to hide the contacts button.

I'm running Safari Version 11.0.1

Fiddle to reproduce:

https://jsfiddle.net/27n5jL40/1/

```
<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
```

Hiding the auto-fill-button

```
input::-webkit-contacts-auto-fill-button {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none !important;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I realize this answer probably comes a bit late, BUT I think I can help.  I have found empirically that Safari get its hints from a) the name of the field, b) the associated label, or c) adjacent text.  It figures out things like field names "name", "firstname", "lastname", and labels or adjacent text like "name", "First name", "Last name".

In my application, it was competing with a custom autofill.  I defeated my dropdown as follows:

I changed my field name from `xx_firstname` to `mxyzptlk`, and the label from `First Name` to `F&zwnj;irst N&zwnj;ame`.  The `&zwnj;` character is a zero width non-joiner.  You can't see it on the screen, but it appears to defeat Safari - at least for now!

Wish I'd found some clever `css`, but this was the best I could come up with.

Comment: Thanks for this @wordragon. I'm sure it's correct but my content management system (which supplies the text for the labels) is not good with HTML Entities like &zwnj; so if anyone else sees this and finds a solution please don't hesitate to post! I will too of course.

Comment: @ScalaEnthusiast You can check out this somewhat more [active discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058018/how-to-disable-autocomplete-in-address-fields-for-safari)

Answer (score 0):

I think in the time since this was asked and now, Apple has made it easier to fix this... just go to the Safari app on your Mac, choose Safari > Settings, click AutoFill, then make sure “Using information from my contacts” is deselected.